# Accessing http session attributes from Freemarker directive

Tags: freemarker

Is that possible to access http session attributes from within Freemarker custom directive? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's up to the Web Application Framework if it puts such variables into the data-model (template context); FreeMarker doesn't do anything like that itself. Although, if the Web Application Framework is using `freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet`, it should be like `Session.someAttributeName`.

Comment: Thanks ddekany for your reply. I'm using dropwizard and it has integrated support for freemarker templates, but it is not using FreemarkerServlet internally. Therefore, on freemarker template I can't do something like ${Session.attribute}.

Comment: Then probably you can just add whatever you need from the session to the `View` as a JavaBean property. Pure MVC templates shouldn't deal with session and such anyway, they just should get the user name or whatever they need to display, without knowing where it comes from (session, session and DB, cookie, etc). Or maybe there's a way to expose something to all views... I don't know drop wizard.

Comment: Right, there is a way to expose session attributes via View, I thought there is a way to work with'em straight from the freemarker template in dropwizard. Thanks anyway!